# Regular exppresion tuning

Tags: java, regex

I use the following regular expression for validating one of my text areas:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

- It allows alpha numeric
- It Avoids first space to be blank
- It Allow blanks after first character

How should i modify it to be able to allow the following characters:

- coma (,)
- semicolon (;)
- colon (:)
- euro symbol (€)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z\d:;,\u20AC][A-Za-z\d :;,\u20AC]+$
```

- `\d` is any digit
- `\u20AC` is the unicode value for euro (`€`)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the expressions already mentioned, you can use `\p{Sc}` to match any currency symbol and `\p{P}` for any punctuation character.

For more character classes have a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,;:€][ a-zA-Z0-9,;:€]+$
```

As Tim mentioned, it's also generally safer to not rely on the text encoding of your source file:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,;:\u20AC][ a-zA-Z0-9,;:\u20AC]+$
```